# KeyError = "static" when installing psycopg2 on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, psycopg2, keyerror

I tried installing psygopg2 in a virtual environment like so:

```
$ pip3 install psycopg2
```

And My Terminal prints the following:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\7480\projects\web\api-wars-python-buhinalba\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\7480\projects\web\api-wars-python-buhinalba\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\7480\projects\web\api-wars-python-buhinalba\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 412, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "c:\users\7480\projects\web\api-wars-python-buhinalba\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 82, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "c:\users\7480\projects\web\api-wars-python-buhinalba\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 778, in install
    scheme = get_scheme(
  File "c:\users\7480\projects\web\api-wars-python-buhinalba\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 192, in get_scheme
    scripts=scheme["static"],
KeyError: 'static'
```

I didn't find any answers for this particular error, I would appreciate the help, thank you!

Edit:
I updated pip before running this command

Comment: Try upgrading your Pip version with `python -m pip install -U pip`; that looks like a Pip bug.

Comment: My pip is fully updated (pip 20.2.2)